# System.OutOfMemoryException is thrown when adding integers to a list

Tags: c#, out-of-memory

I'm an extremely amateur C# developer who's trying to make this console program on macOS using Visual Studio. I do it in school, but I'm self-taught and have been working on this for less than two weeks, so it's entirely possible that I'm missing some simple solution.

I've made a program that reads off a text file filled with prime numbers and converts it into a list, then begins to generate prime numbers while adding them to the list and file, and simultaneously reporting out information every time it finds a new one.

Here's the code I have:

```
String fileLocation = "Prime Number List.txt"; //sets the file location to the root of where the program is stored

if (!File.Exists(fileLocation)) //tests if the file has already been created
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fileLocation))
    {
        Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("2"); //if not, it creates the file and creates the initial prime number of 2
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
}


List<string> fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation).ToList(); //imports the list of prime numbers from the file
List<int> listOfPrimeNumbers = fileContents.ConvertAll(s => Int32.Parse(s)); //converts the list into the integer variable type


int currentNumber = listOfPrimeNumbers[listOfPrimeNumbers.Count() - 1]; //sets the current number to the most recent prime number
bool isPrime; //initializing the primality test variable
int numbersGeneratedThisSession = 0; //initializing the variable for the amount of primes found in this session
var loopStart = DateTime.Now; //initializes the program start time, ignoring the time taken to load the file list

while (true)
{
    isPrime = true; //defaults the number to prime
    currentNumber++; //repeats the cycle for the next number
    double currentNumberRoot = Math.Sqrt(System.Convert.ToDouble(currentNumber));
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfPrimeNumbers.Count; i++) //cyles through all of the primes in the list. no reason to divide by composites, as any number divisible by a
                                                            //composite would be divisible by the prime factors of that composite anyway, thus if we were to divide by
                                                            //every number it would slow down the program
    {
        if (listOfPrimeNumbers[i] < Math.Sqrt(System.Convert.ToDouble(currentNumber))) //filters out any prime numbers greater than the square root of the current number, as any potential
                                                                                            //factor pair would have one of the values less than or equal to the square root
        {
            if (currentNumber % listOfPrimeNumbers[i] == 0) //checks for the even division of the current number by the current prime
            {
                isPrime = false; //if an even division is found, it reports that the number isn't false and breaks the loop
                break;
            }
        }

        else
            break; //if no even divisons are found, then it reaches this point with the primality test variable still true, and breaks the loop



    }
    if (isPrime) //this section of the code activates when the primality test variable is true
    {
        listOfPrimeNumbers.Add(currentNumber); //adds the new prime to the list
        File.AppendAllText(fileLocation, Environment.NewLine + currentNumber); //adds the new prime to the file on a new line
        numbersGeneratedThisSession++; //raises the counter for the prime numbers generated in this session
        var runtime = DateTime.Now - loopStart; //calculates the runtime of the program, excluding the time taken to load the file into the list
        int runtimeInSecs = (runtime.Milliseconds / 1000) + runtime.Seconds + (runtime.Minutes * 60) + (runtime.Hours * 360) + (runtime.Days * 86400); //converts the datetime var into an int of seconds
        int generationSpeed = runtimeInSecs == 0 ? 0 : numbersGeneratedThisSession / runtimeInSecs;
        Console.WriteLine("\nI've generated {0} prime numbers, {1} of those being in the current session." +
                          "\nI've been running for {2}, which means I've been generating numbers at a speed of {3} primes per second. " +
                          "\nThe largest prime I've generated so far is {4}, which is {5} digits long.", 
                          listOfPrimeNumbers.Count(), numbersGeneratedThisSession, runtime, generationSpeed, currentNumber, currentNumber.ToString().Length);
    }
}
```

I keep getting the exception on the "listOfPrimeNumbers.Add(currentNumber);" part. I've read up on similar questions, and the most common solution to other people's problems was to set gcAllowVeryLargeObjects to true, to break the 2GB limit. That would be a temporary fix for me, however as the list will continually get larger over time, there will be a point when it hits the limits of my computer's capabilities rather than the limit of visual studio's cap.

I'm wondering if there's some sort of technique that more experienced developers use to circumvent this issue, like splitting the data into multiple lists, doing something different than I did to streamline the code, etc. I know that due to the nature of my program it's unavoidable that eventually the data will grow too large, but I'm trying to postpone that for as long as possible as the file right now is less than half a gig, which is an unreasonably small amount of memory to be crashing the program.

I'd also like to note that I ran this program for around an hour a day while I was working on the statistic feedback (meaning that the file reading, writing, and generation code itself were largely untouched during this time) for the past week. I had no problems booting it up any of those times, and the final time it ran went smoothly (didn't crash due to the out of memory exception). I only encountered this problem today when I tried starting it up again.

Comment: `while (true)`. Hmm...

Comment: tip: don't do a sqrt on every pass of a loop - do it once *before* the loop. If you **absolutely must** compare against a sqrt - it is usually preferable to square the smaller number and compare squares instead

Comment: `currentNumber` is initialized with the last number of the list. You don't want to add this to the list again, so I suggest moving `currentNumber++;` to the beginning of the `while` loop.

Comment: You add integers to  the list `listOfPrimeNumbers` in a infinite loop. *Of course* you will sooner or later fill up finite memory with infinite write opeartions. This whole while loop seems oddly missplaced. All it does is call the for loop over and over.

Comment: Isn't the first `if` in the loop the wrong way around? You only check for divisibility if the prime is *greater* that the sqrt? Wouldn't that result in your code deciding that every number is prime?

Comment: I mean, you could save your prime numbers into a file and then later stream the file again to do your calculations, ofc this is a lot slower than in-memory but it would shift the system limitation from RAM to storage space.

Comment: @ Patrick Hofman: Yes, I know. I did it that way because I tried coding it so that the loop ran until I hit the 'x' key to stop it, but it didn't quite work. So now I just run it until I manually terminate the program.

@ Marc Gravell: Thanks, advice taken and applied

@ Henrik: Advice taken and applied.

@ Christopher: In what way do you mean oddly misplaced? Some sort of loop is necessary to loop the generation processes or else the program would generate one prime and quit.

Comment: After a quick google, there's >300Billion primes currently known and those numbers can be huge, potentially taking up terabytes of memory. You _will_ run out of memory and/or disk space eventually.
As a learning exercise, I'm tempted to say that you've accomplished what you were after, even though the actual method you took could be optimised substantially (i.e. not testing even numbers!)

Comment: @DanielleSummers - but you won't encounter those particular problems when the variable you're using to store the candidates is defined as `int`.

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever: I typed it up wrong in the post. I had a lot of technical issues copy/pasting it into the text editor here, so I typed up the code manually. I'll fix the OP in a sec.
@ Tobias Wurth: How do you suggest I accomplish something like that?
@ Danielle Summers Damien pretty much said what I was going to. However I'd also like to add that the simplest way to test if a number is even is to divide it by two, and two just happens to be the very first prime number. Therefore, I already test if it's even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're searching for primes with his program, you're going to run out of memory if you just attempt to store this in said memory.

Splitting your lists will help a little, as stated, but in the end you'll run into the same problem; 5 groups of 3 items is 15 items, grouped apart or not.  You're going to fill up your memory quickly.

I think your problem may be here:

```
List<string> fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation).ToList(); //imports the list of prime numbers from the file
List<int> listOfPrimeNumbers = fileContents.ConvertAll(s => Int32.Parse(s)); //converts the list into the integer variable type
```

Both of these `Lists<T>` are unnecessary.  Your file has carriage returns in it (you're inserting `Environment.NewLine`on your entries), so presuming you want to just continue where you left off, you need exactly one value from that file:

```
//note that I used ReadLines, not ReadAllLines
 int lastNumber;
 if(!int.TryParse(File.ReadLines(fileLocation).ToList().Last(), out lastNumber))
 {
      //last value wasn't a valid integer.  Start over. 
      lastNumber = 1;
 }
```

Then, execute all of your logic using `lastNumber`, write to the file when it's prime, and don't store collections in memory at all.   This will make your new limiting factor the storage space on the destination computer.   If you run out of memory loading the file and getting its last string, you'll need to put together a bit of code that involves reading the file backward, but since this is a more academic project, I doubt you need to take it that far.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but unless I read the entire contents of the file, it will severely slow down the process itself (the primality check will divide by every number less than the square root, rather than just every prime.) If you take a look at the primality test itself, you'll most likely see the issue. Unless using a similar loop to read off each line of the file is what you're suggesting?

Comment: Yes, I think you'd be better off reading from the text file and just taking smaller hunks of data for calculation, instead of trying to load the whole file.   You don't need to necessarily load them one at a time, but loading them in small chunks will keep your memory footprint under control. If you are using an SSD in the target environment, the performance difference between using smaller arrays or just one-off reads should be negligible.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into how to do this. Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Individual arrays or lists in .NET are bound by all of:

- the 2GiB object limit (unless `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects` is enabled)
- the available process memory (especially relevant for 32-bit processes)
- 2,146,435,071 items per dimension (2,147,483,591 for single-byte values)

If you are getting *anywhere near* these problems, then yes: you need another approach. Moving to multiple individual lists that you treat as a composite block should serve as a stop-gap, but... I don't think this is ultimately a very scalable approach for computing prime numbers.

Comment: A complete list of 32 bit primes should take ~800MB of space and be composed of 203280220 entries. So the only limit they should be hitting should be the process memory - if they were in fact computing primes which I don't think they are due to a bug.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that's fair; 800MB in a chunk is *about* when you start hitting major allocation problems, though (even on 64-bit) - especially for list doubling. But: you're probably right about including some non-primes.

Comment: If `listOfPrimeNumbers[0]` is `2` then the logic goes wrong as soon as we're going through the loop for `4`. `listOfPrimeNumbers[0]` is not greater than the sqrt of 4 and so, according to the logic here, `4` is prime. The same applies for every number greater than 4, by the same logic.

Comment: Going off the code I posted, Damien's entirely right. I switched around the sign when typing it up.